# SQL Date Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me understand the SQL `Select` statement below:

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
```

The `0`s are throwing me off.

Answer (score 5):

The date `0` is interpreted as `1/1/1900`.

This statement is determining the number of days since `1/1/1900`:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
```

It's wrapped in another call that adds that many days, minus 1, to `1/1/1990` (`0`).

```
DATEADD(DAY, <from above> - 1, 0)
```

Essentially giving you yesterday's date.

Comment: More specifically, it will give you *midnight* yesterday.  It strips the time from the datetime value which getdate() returns.